# what is the clojurescript equivalent to 'var'?

Tags: clojurescript

In clojure, `(var some-function)` and `#'some-function` are equivalent.

What is the clojurescript equivalent of `var`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClojureScript also has `var` as a special form. And, in ClojureScript `(var foo)` and `#'foo` are equivalent.

Having said that, ClojureScript's `var` is a bit limited compared to Clojure:

> Vars are not reified at runtime. When the compiler encounters the `var` special form it emits a `Var` instance reflecting **compile time** metadata. (This satisfies many common **static** use cases.)

(Taken from [Differences from Clojure](https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_special_forms).)